# How can I only return the first product when using pd.multiIndex.from_product()? Or a better option

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am using the code below to make a new index for a dataframe.

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Key'],pd.date_range(start='20160101', end='20160301',freq='MS')],names=['key','year_month']))
```

Here is the current ouput:

`0  (A, 2016-01-01 00:00:00)
1   (A, 2016-02-01 00:00:00)
2   (A, 2016-03-01 00:00:00)
3   (A, 2016-01-01 00:00:00)
4   (A, 2016-02-01 00:00:00)
5   (A, 2016-03-01 00:00:00)
6   (A, 2016-01-01 00:00:00)
7   (A, 2016-02-01 00:00:00)
8   (A, 2016-03-01 00:00:00)
9   (B, 2016-01-01 00:00:00)
10  (B, 2016-02-01 00:00:00)
11  (B, 2016-03-01 00:00:00)
12  (B, 2016-01-01 00:00:00)
13  (B, 2016-02-01 00:00:00)
14  (B, 2016-03-01 00:00:00)
15  (B, 2016-01-01 00:00:00)
16  (B, 2016-02-01 00:00:00)
17  (B, 2016-03-01 00:00:00)`

How can I change this code so that I only return the first product? Is there a separate function or an option for from_product?

Desired output:

`0  (A, 2016-01-01 00:00:00)
1   (A, 2016-02-01 00:00:00)
2   (A, 2016-03-01 00:00:00)
3   (B, 2016-01-01 00:00:00)
4   (B, 2016-02-01 00:00:00)
5   (B, 2016-03-01 00:00:00)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `unique`

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Key'].unique(),pd.date_range(start='20160101', end='20160301',freq='MS')],names=['key','year_month']))
```